# How can I recover a file that was overwritten by the download manager?

Tags: windows, download, data-recovery, file-recovery

I was using [blader](http://all-streaming-media.com/record-video-stream/Blader-freeware-RTMP-downloader.htm) to download an RTMP stream with FLV extension. It downloaded a file which was about 5 GB in size.

The file was working, so things were good until I restarted the download and it used the same filename without even asking something like "the file already exists, do you want to rename it?" or "the file will be lost".

Now I have lost 5 GB video. Any way to recover it? I already checked the recycle bin, and it's not there.

I'm using Windows 7 Home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried previous versions if you have it enabled? try going to the root of the drive,  and looking for previous versions there if you dont have it enabled on the specific folder. I think 7 has it enabled by default